# jquery append doesn't work with relational selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, append, relational

the append() method seems to work only with simple selectors like `$("#myid")` but not with relational selector like `$(#myid>ul)`. Do you have the same problem?

EXAMPLE
Try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append_ref

If I change the code this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("p>ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.
 <ol>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
</p>
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

the "Append list item" button doesn't work any more, because `$("p>ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>")` doesn't work, as it has a relational selector.

Comment: There is no button 2 in your html. And that is not a relational selector. Its a child selector. Of course it is relational. :)

Comment: Sorry, the second buttons was cut while typing. it is <button id="btn2">Append list item</button>. 
The selector is a relational selector.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't stopping at the first p element because that element doesn't have an ol child?

Comment: it would be very weird if it stopped at the first p. it should scan the whole DOM.

Comment: When you place an `ol` inside of a `p` element, it terminates the `p` element.  You end up having sibling elements rather than ancestor/child elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery works fine. It's your markup that's screwed up.  It's against the HTML spec to include flow elements like `ol` in a paragraph element. Only phrasing elements are permitted in a `p` element

Paragraphs may only contain phrasing content: [w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-content-model)
Phrasing content does not include the `ol` element: [w3c again](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing)

Notice in the following example how the `$('p + ol')` selector correctly targets the `ol`.  this is because of a little known rule for the `p` element in the HTML spec.  [Paragraphs automatically terminate without the need of an ending paragraph tag if they are followed by `ol` or other flow content. (See "Tag Omission")](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags)

```js
$('p + ol').css({color: 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  WARNING! this is invalid markup.
  <ol>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>List</li>
  </ol>
</p>
```

Comment: You gave me the solution, thank you! I replaced the <p> with a <div> and now it works.